# How to show WIFI connection's properties dialog in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1, when I right click a WIFI connection, nothing happens. In Windows 8, there will be a menu and I can view its properties by clicking the "View Properties" menu item. How to do that in Windows 8.1?

Comment: it seams to be removed in 8.1: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1183285-right-click-properties-missing-on-networks-in-81/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click the Network icon in taskbar. In the dropdown menu click 'Open Network and Sharing Centre'. It will show you your current connections. In the windows that appears, click the highlighted link in the snip. [image]

In the new windows that appears, click on ' Wireless Properties'. Your are on your WiFi network properties window !

Comment: Nice try - but what if I don't get that far? My wireless network refuses to connect in the first place! Any idea where I can find the dialog to select the encryption settings and could enter the network password, etc.?
And I don't mean that blue-ish slide-in with the white fields that then always only yields "can't connect to the network" :-(

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do though it appears MS made a few changes in WIN8.1 that sort of hides a few thins directly from the GUI we are all used to. You can use the command prompt to work it out. The following should help. Also the part below that has the security should help solve the earlier question you asked about showing the password. That post has been blocked so i couldnt respond to help. Here we go...

1. Right click command prompt and run as administrator
2. netsh wlan show network (Will show all networks available)
3. netsh wlan show driver (Will show your driver details and capabilities)
4. netsh wlan show profile (will show all network profiles on your machine)
5. netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security (will show all details of the hostednetwork including current password)

I hope this helps you and anyone else in the same soup... chao

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Sway your mouse on the right to awaken menus. Select "Settings." Then click on "Control Panel.

Step 2: Click on "Network and Internet" Select "View network status and tasks"

Step 3: On the upper left, under Control Panel Home. Select "Change adapter settings"

Step 4: Select the connection and right click for "Properties"

Answer (score 1):

`Win + S` then search `ncpa.cpl` and hit enter would open the Network Connections dialog.

Answer (score -1):

1. From Windows Search Bar type `ncpa.cpl` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. In the window that opens double-click Wi-Fi
3. Click on wireless properties