# How to show VPN connection properties in windows 8.1

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-8.1

Microsoft help says to right-click on the connection to edit it, but that does not appear to do anything in Windows 8.1

This is similar to [How to show WIFI connection's properties dialog in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/678162/how-to-show-wifi-connections-properties-dialog-in-windows-8-1), but the solution to that problem does not appear to apply to VPN connections.

Anyone figured this one out?

**Edit:**

There appears to be two completely different ways of setting VPN properties in Windows 8.1, each of which allows you to set different and only slightly overlapping properties: the "Change PC Settings" way, which lets you edit log-in credentials and proxy settings; and the "Control Panel" way, which lets you configure VPN security settings (such as L2TP vs PPTP etc.) and VPN Networking settings (such as IPv4 default gateway, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change anything about a VPN connection you have already created, you can do it from PC Settings.

Go to Network and then to Connections. In the VPN connections, select the connection you want to configure and press Edit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized anything useful could be done from Change PC Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out a few other ways to do this myself. I'm glad Microsoft is protecting us desktop users from the evil right-click and even more evil context menus by burying settings deep in poorly named configuration hierarchies. Editorial comments almost done...

So open the Control Panel. I won't mention how because the method of doing so could change at any moment.

If you see "Network and Sharing Center", select it. Otherwise, select "Network and Internet", followed by "Network and Sharing Center".

Now for the obvious part: select "Change adapter settings".

Then you can click on the connection you want to edit, and a ribbon-like set of commands such as "Change settings of this connection" will appear.

Or if you are Luddite, right-click on the connection, and pick an option like "Properties" from the context menu that appears... but be prepared to be shamed for right clicking and using a context menu.

An even simpler way, discovered by accident.  Just type "vpn" at the Start screen, and the option to manage VPN connections appears.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for Win10 the properties tab wouldn't bring anything up.

I found this on technet - put the name of the VPN you want to change
The command is per VPN and NOT global

Run a tracert to an internet address to test before and after the change to prove the change.

You have to open PowerShell as an Administrator and input these two commands in the Command Line Interface:

```
Get-VpnConnection
Set-VpnConnection -Name "VPN Name" -SplitTunneling $True
```

Comment: The author is using Windows 8.1 not Windows 10.  So it is to be expected that an answer, written towards the version of Windows the author of question was using, wouldn't work on a newer version of Windows.