# How to access wireless network properties to configure a new connection in Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

At my University, I need to connect to a secure network that requires pre-configuring authentication settings in my computer's network properties.

On Windows 7, you could access these settings via right-click on an available wireless network and choosing "Properties".  This doesn't work for me in Windows 10; double-clicking or right-clicking on a network does nothing.

As someone explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/678296/498587), you can go to the Network & Sharing Center and click a network you're already connected to, then get to the properties.  However, I need to access the properties for a network to which I'm not yet connected in order to initially set up the configuration.

**In Windows 10, what is the route to access the connection properties dialog for a wireless network that can be seen as available but for which the connection has not yet been configured?**

Comment: A disconnected network wouldn't have any properties one would assume.

Comment: Take a look at pages 2-4 of [this PDF](http://www1.uwindsor.ca/its/wireless/system/files/Configuring%20WIN%207%20for%20Uwindsor_Secure.pdf). Things I need to change before I connect.

Comment: Is all of this just to ask where to find the configuration screens for a network you've selected?  There are various routes to get a list of the networks the computer sees as existing.  I'm not familiar with Win 10, specifically, but typically, right-clicking or double-clicking on an available network will open that properties/configuration window.

Comment: Nope, not at all. As I already said on Windows 7 you could right click and select properties but you can't on 10 (or 8/8.1 to my knowledge). Why even respond if you're going to be condescending? [Here's a GIF](http://i.imgur.com/l0md6Gq.gif) of me spamming double click on a network the computer sees as existing. As you can see, no properties/configuration window pops up.

Comment: I wasn't being condescending, I was trying to make sense of your question and attempt to offer help.  With all of the verbiage in the question, you didn't describe what happens via the "usual" routes, which you clarified in your comment.  You link to some screens that are described as available after you are connected.  Those same screens should be available (and are needed), before you connect.  So the question you're trying to answer appears to be what I asked in my first sentence: where to find those screens starting from a list of available networks.

Comment: If you mean [this screenshot then](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j1rkE.png) you're confused. That page doesn't list all available network connections. It lists what you're connected to on each type (above the person had an Ethernet cable plugged in and also was on WiFi) Here, look at a [full view of the page](http://i.imgur.com/q7gGnxg.png) as it currently is on my screen and you'll see.

Comment: See what you think of the edit.  In the last link in your comment above, there's a "Set up a new connection or network".  Where does that lead?

Comment: BTW, I was referring earlier to http://i.imgur.com/l0md6Gq.gif, which you described as spamming double-clicking on a network the computer sees.

Comment: I will try setup a new network when I'm on campus, I can't much test it now. Thanks

Comment: If you choose "manually connect to a WiFi network" you can create a new profile that way (under Set up a new connection or network as you said). So ridiculous considering all you had to do was right click on Windows 7 and click properties.

Comment: So you got it working?  If so, it's a good excuse to celebrate!  Consider posting your own answer.  You can't be the only person with this problem and your efforts to solve it could help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'm thankful I got this to work but I'm also embarassed how it was hidden in plain sight.*

- Right Click on your network icon in the taskbar and click "Open Network and Sharing Center"

[image]

- Find setup a new connection

[image]

- Select Manually Connect to a wireless network

[image]

- Now, is where you will enter the SSID and applicable security info for your network. **Even if you aren't connected, you can create a profile and access advanced properties**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The OP's request has not been addressed, but ignored.

In Windows 10 you can NOT edit an already configured wireless networks settings without being connected to it first. In Windows 7 you can.

In Windows 10 you can create networks manually, which exposes the GUI they want, and you can delete them as well.

But to edit them afterwards you have to at least attempt to connect to them. However if you mess up those settings and put it in a state where it would never connect it cannot be edited and must be deleted.

This is as step backwards from Windows 7.

Comment: You appear to be correct. Not being able to reconfig an existing wifi profile when its not connected, which is precisely when a reconfig is likely needed, is completely insane.

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/manage_wireless_networks.html can invoke the native management UI "Edit Wireless Profile" for disconnected profiles. What garbage win10 is.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like a recent Win 10 update changed the way to access the wireless "advance" properties.

In my case the way to access this is via "Control Panel".
Then click "Network and Internet", then on the right side, click "Network and Sharing Center". Then you'll see the "Setup a new connection or network". Afterwards follow procedures from Insane's post above.