# How to access properties for an existing wireless network profile in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How do you access the "Wireless Network Properties" dialog for an existing wireless network profile in Windows 10? This dialog could easily be reached for any wireless network in Windows 7 and 8, but it appears to have been hidden for some reason in Windows 10, and the settings available in the "Settings" application have never been sufficient in my experience.

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/974490) describes how to access the properties dialog for a new network, but I am specifically trying to open it for previously set up networks.

I am using Windows 10 Home, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to Network & Security\Wi-Fi\ Manage known networks to add new network or forget saved network.

Besides, you could check Wireless Properties from Network and Sharing Center.
[image]

However, can’t find a way to access the full properties again of existing networks like Windows 7, whether you are using Home edition, Pro edition or Enterprise edition.